# creating a object whose instance will be updated upon change in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, reactjs

Recently, I was asked this question:-

```
a = {
  "aa": "aa",
  "bb": "bb",
  "dddd": 19,
}
```

I was asked to create an instance of the above-mentioned object such that the instance will be updated whenever this object updates.

What I can think of is:-

```
b=a
```

as b and a's reference will same so whenever a is updated, b will also update.

I tried to create an object using Object.create, like

```
b = Object.create(a)
```

but it will always returns {}

does

> b=a

signifies that b is an instance of a? ()

So, what is the solution to this question?

Comment: did you try b = {...a};

Comment: It's because b is new object inherits a.

a = {
  aa: "aa",
  bb: "bb",
  dddd: 19,
};

b = Object.create(a);

b.aa; // prints "aa"

a.aa ="bb";

b.aa; // prints "bb"

Comment: b.__proto__ contains aa's properties

Comment: @ Suresh Kumar Ariya , that i have tried but it will result in a new referenceed object. but the question is I was asked to create an instance of the above-mentioned object such that the instance will be updated whenever this object updates.

Answer (score 0):

From MDN:

> The [**`Object.create()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) method creates a **new** object, using an existing object as the prototype of the newly created object.

Focus on the **new** word there. A new Object would be created in memory.

What this means is, that a will be acting as `a` Prototype for `b`. You would still be able to access the fields on `a` using `b` by the `.` member access pattern.

Here, give this a try:

```js
var a = {
  "aa": "aa",
  "bb": "bb",
  "dddd": 19,
}

var b = Object.create(a);

console.log(b.aa);
console.log(b.bb);
console.log(b.dddd);
```

But if you change anything in `b`, then the change would not replicate in `a`, since `a` and `b` are now pointing to two different objects in memory.

`b = a` does not signify that b is an instance of a. It just means what you initially said, that `a` and `b` are pointing to the same object in memory. So if you change anything via `b`, the same is going to get reflected in `a`.

**UPDATE:**

There are other ways of doing this though. You can, for example, use a `BehaviorSubject`, and instantiate it with `a`.

You can then `subscribe` to it and assign the value to `b`.

Now, whenever you want to change the value of a, just call `next` on the `BehaviorSubject`. And then, since you've already `subscribe`d to this and assigned it to `b`, `b` is always going to get the updated value.

Comment: I was asked to create an instance of the above-mentioned object such that the instance will be updated whenever this object updates. how this can be achieved then?

Comment: Just by using `b = a;` That way, since `b` and `a` would be pointing to the same object in memory, if you change anything on the object via `b`, the same would be reflected on the object if you try to get it via `a`.

Comment: So, is this the only it can be done or is there any other way as well?